# Can we know the available money in anyone account by getting only his payapl accountID

Tags: paypal

**Hey guys please confirm me regarding my query :**

> > I am working on "Online Shopping Site" & done all the transaction by Paypal. SO my question is "Can we know the available money in anyone account by getting only his payapl accountID".

**If anyone have an idea kindly share with me.**

Comment: You need to know how much money your users have in their accounts???
Do you declare your bank balance when you buy something from the supermarket?

Comment: Actually, its need of my project that's we can deduct some money from user ($3 charge). This could be only happened when we know the amount which we deduct is available in his account.

Comment: This sounds very bad, Im sure Paypal will handle the case where the user doesn't have enough money in their account and return an error of some sort...

Comment: Please note that a PayPal account does not necessarily need to have any balance. For example you can set up an account to withdraw money as needed from a real bank account, so the account itself is always “empty”.

Comment: Hi Poke, This could be a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not know it.

Paypal says very clear, they never share that information's.